# How can I easily install missing hplip dependencies?

Tags: package-management, hplip

Having installed HPLIP on my 10.10 system, the HP Photosmart 420 gives "Device Communication Error" code 5012 when I try to print. Running `hp-check` lists 11 missing dependencies. Do I have to install them all one by one or is there an easier way to get the printer going? What is the command to install a dependency?

Comment: On a side note, your system should have all required dependencies for `hplip` already installed if you installed it from the Ubuntu repos through the package management tool of your choice. Or did you install it from elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terminal

```
sudo apt-get -f install hplip
```

should fix it

There is the other option here : [source](http://hplip.sourceforge.net/install/index.html)

which has the download and installation instructions. It has a section that will run

DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION

This is the direct download [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.12.2/hplip-3.12.2.run/download?use_mirror=iweb)

Comment: I installed hplip as indicated but it still says missing dependancies. When I tried installing the first missing dep. ie "CUPS devel" it could not find said dependancy.

Comment: are you able to give us the print from terminal as to the error message

Comment: Thanks for the info BlueXrider. When I do that I get this:Could not open the file /home/mystuff/Downloads/hplip-3.12.2.run using the Unicode (UTF-8) character encoding.Which char encoding do I need?

Comment: this is the web site http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html follow the instructions at the left of it. Where it says Install and Setup

Comment: Thanks BlueXrider. Did that and fixed all dependancies. Rebooted PC.But still get this:Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/Photosmart_420_series?serial=CN59N250BX04HP
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/Photosmart_420.ppd
PPD Description: HP Photosmart 420 Series, hpcups 3.10.6
Printer status: printer Photosmart_420 is idle.  enabled since Fri 09 Mar 2012 17:30:26 GMT
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/usb/Photosmart_420_series?serial=CN59N250BX04HP
error: Device not found
error: Communication status: Failed

Comment: @Rosco That is a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/521909 This may be a work around. Drop to #2 answer http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/hplip-device-manager-unable-to-find-printers-on-current-625320/

Answer (score 4):

The dependencies can be installed following instructions here:
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/manual/distros/ubuntu.html

hplip is not a dependency, it's the package that *contains* hp-check and other utilities. The dependencies such as "CUPS devel", "Python devel", "PyQt4" and so on can be installed using the following command for Ubuntu 10.04 and up, according to current info from link above (but I recommend checking for updated info):

```
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2 cups libcups2-dev cups-bsd cups-client libcupsimage2-dev libdbus-1-dev build-essential ghostscript openssl libjpeg62-dev libsnmp-dev libtool libusb-dev python-imaging policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-dbus python-gobject python-dev python-notify python python-reportlab libsane libsane-dev sane-utils xsane
```

Comment: Wondering what's the up-to-date way to do this with newer versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem of the printer being seen but not printing. I actually manually added a new instance of the same printer with a new name and description and stuff and it started printing. I'm using SteamOS and I first used:

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```

Then I have chosen the identified printer (k209a) but renamed to just the model, added location and description. When it prompted to print a test page I did so without hope but the "Stupid Old Black printer" started to print :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the needed packages are, you can simply run the usual `sudo apt-get install` in a terminal, followed by the names of the packages required.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem. The way for this to work is to install the **hplip toolbox** from the software center. Then `sudo hp-toolbox` and then you should be able to install the correct plugin. In fact if you type `hp-` then tab you should see a bunch of for HP printers.

Comment: -1 just tried this and get **warning: hp-toolbox should not be run as root/superuser**, followed immediately by **error: dBus initialization error. Exiting**.