# HP Pinter driver (HPLIP) installations methods

Tags: 14.04, synaptic, hplip

Sorry but I have another newbie question.

I installed HPLIP using the command line method, but ended up with the common GyPO error. Sad to say in trying to correct the issue I ended up with a bigger mess.

After doing some research I found that I missing some Python dependences (more than one) and I also reference to using Synaptic or the Software center

Question 1)
Which way is the best installation better?

Question 2)
If were to use Synaptic would it take care of this dependence and only others that may exist?

Comment: Have you seen [Which is the best way to install new hplip versions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10082/which-is-the-best-way-to-install-new-hplip-versions) and [How can I easily install missing hplip dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110580/how-can-i-easily-install-missing-hplip-dependencies)

Comment: What is the common GyPo error? A search found nothing. What error do you actually get?

Comment: Search on "PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK"

Comment: Bain, Yes I did, but the link to the HP site came up as Spanish (I think)

Comment: Try http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install.html

Comment: Bain, Your link is the same one I used that has the PyOS error. Which I just noticed I had a typo in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you from my experience you can just install it from the Software Centre (look for hplip package) without so many annoying workarounds