# hplip 3.14.10, no python-devel

Tags: printing, package-management, dependencies, hplip

Tech specs: Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5420 @ 2.50GHz × 8 , 32GB Memory, ubuntu 14.04 (64bit).

HP 5660 envy aio

```
richard@Doc:~$ cd Desktop
richard@Doc:~/Desktop$  sh hplip-3.14.10.run
Creating directory hplip-3.14.10
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.14.10 Self Extracting Archive...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.14.10)
HPLIP Installer ver. 5.1

Copyright (c) 2001-13 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Installer log saved in: hplip-install_Fri-10-Oct-2014_20:18:49.log

\
note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.


INSTALLATION MODE
-----------------
Automatic mode will install the full HPLIP solution with the most common options.
Custom mode allows you to choose installation options to fit specific requirements.

Please choose the installation mode (a=automatic*, c=custom, q=quit) : a

Initializing. Please wait...


INTRODUCTION
------------
This installer will install HPLIP version 3.14.10 on your computer.
Please close any running package management systems now (YaST, Adept, Synaptic, Up2date, etc).


DISTRO/OS CONFIRMATION
----------------------
Distro appears to be Ubuntu 14.04.

Is "Ubuntu 14.04" your correct distro/OS and version (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


ENTER USER PASSWORD
-------------------
Please enter the sudoer (richard)'s password: 


INSTALLATION NOTES
------------------
Enable the universe/multiverse repositories. Also be sure you are using the Ubuntu "Main" Repositories. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more information.  Disable the CD-ROM/DVD source if you do not have the Ubuntu installation media inserted in the drive.

Please read the installation notes. Press <enter> to continue or 'q' to quit: 


RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
warning: There are 5 missing REQUIRED dependencies.
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-devel (CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libusb (libusb - USB library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libtool (libtool - Library building support services)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-image (CUPS image - CUPS image development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libjpeg (libjpeg - JPEG library)


INSTALL MISSING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
warning: There are 4 missing OPTIONAL dependencies.
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency for option 'network': libcrypto (libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency for option 'network': libnetsnmp-devel (libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency for option 'fax': dbus (DBus - Message bus system)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency for option 'scan': sane-devel (SANE - Scanning library development files)


CHECKING FOR NETWORK CONNECTION
-------------------------------
Network connection present.


RUNNING PRE-PACKAGE COMMANDS
----------------------------
sudo dpkg --configure -a (Pre-depend step 1)
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes -f (Pre-depend step 2)
sudo apt-get update (Pre-depend step 3)
OK


DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes cups-bsd'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes cups-client'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libusb-1.0.0-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libtool'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcupsimage2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libjpeg-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes openssl'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libsnmp-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes snmp-mibs-downloader'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libdbus-1-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libsane-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
HPLIP-3.14.3 exists, this may conflict with the new one being installed.
Do you want to ('i'= Remove and Install*, 'o'= Overwrite, 'q'= Quit)?   :i
Starting uninstallation...
HPLIP uninstallation is completed


RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS
-----------------------------
OK


RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------


PRE-BUILD COMMANDS
------------------
OK


BUILD AND INSTALL
-----------------
Running './configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/ppd/HP --libdir=/usr/lib --prefix=/usr --enable-udev-acl-rules --enable-qt4 --disable-libusb01_build --enable-doc-build --disable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-udev_sysfs_rules --disable-policykit --enable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Configure failed with error: python-devel not found

richard@Doc:~$ sudo apt-get install python-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-devel
```

Comment: no one has an idea on how to fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110580/how-can-i-easily-install-missing-hplip-dependencies) suggests quite a long list of dependencies you have to install before running the script, but I got the same error as you and simply did `sudo apt-get install python-dev`, then re-ran the script.

It's installed now and I can see my HP OfficeJet Pro 8620 printer.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev` worked for me on Debian 8.6 64bits

Answer (score 0):

you can enter command below to checkout your default python version:
`$ python -V`
like me, my computer output is like:
`Python 3.9.10`
then download dependency with 'sudo apt-get install python[version]-dev':
`$ sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev`